# C++ Calling template specialized function

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, template-specialization

I have the following piece of code. The code compiles fine:

File A.h

```
#include <memory>

class B {};
class C {};

template <class T1>
class A
{
public:
    explicit A(T1 t1);
    template <class T2, class T3>
    void foo(T1 t, T2 t2, T3 t3);
    template <B&, C&>
    void foo(T1 t, const std::shared_ptr<B>& b, const std::shared_ptr<C>& c);
};

#include "A-inl.h"
```

File A-inl.h

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

template <class T1>
A<T1>::A(T1 t)
{
}

template <class T1>
template <class T2, class T3>
void A<T1>::foo(T1 t, T2 t2, T3 t3)
{
    std::cout << "Foo templatized" << std::endl;
}

template <class T1>
template <B&, C&>
void A<T1>::foo(T1 t, const std::shared_ptr<B>& b, const std::shared_ptr<C>& c)
{
    std::cout << "Foo specalized" << std::endl;
}
```

File main.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include<memory>

#include "A.h"

class X{};
class Y{};
class Z{};

int
main()
{
    X x;
    A<X> a(x);
    Y y;
    Z z;
    a.foo(x, y, z);
    const std::shared_ptr<B> b = std::make_shared<B>(B());
    const std::shared_ptr<C> c = std::make_shared<C>(C());
    a.foo(x, b, c);
}
```

Output:

```
Foo templatized
Foo templatized
```

I had two questions:

(1) How do I make the call to the specialized version of the template function foo.

(2) I have

```
 template <B&, C&>
 void foo(T1 t, const std::shared_ptr<B>& b, const std::shared_ptr<C>& c);
```

What is the type in :

```
const std::shared_ptr<B>& b
                      --
```

Is it

```
B& or B.
```

Comment: Do you know what `template <B&, C&>` means?

Comment: You have an overload, not a specialisation. And you probably want to remove `template <B&, C&>`.

Comment: @cpplearner My template can will take a L-value of B ?
am I correct.

Comment: @Jarod42 I cannot do a explicit template specialization with template<B, C>

Answer (score 1):

```
template <B& /*unnamed*/, C& /*unnamed*/>
void foo(T1 t, const std::shared_ptr<B>& b, const std::shared_ptr<C>& c);
```

is an overload of `foo`, not a specialization.

It can be called by specifying the non-deducible reference:

```
static B globalB;
static C globalC;

int
main()
{
    X x;
    A<X> a(x);
    Y y;
    Z z;
    a.foo(x, y, z);
    const std::shared_ptr<B> b = std::make_shared<B>(B());
    const std::shared_ptr<C> c = std::make_shared<C>(C());
    a<globalB, globalC>.foo(x, b, c);
}
```

> What is the type in : `const std::shared_ptr<B>& b`

`B` is not a template parameter, but a class. so `B` **is** the class `B`.

Answer (score 0):

Because B and C are ordinary classes, you dont need template parameters in specialisation

class definition:

```
template <class T1>
class A
{
public:
    explicit A(T1 t1);
    template <class T2, class T3>
    void foo(T1 t, T2 t2, T3 t3);

    void foo(T1 t, const std::shared_ptr<B>& b, const std::shared_ptr<C>& c); 
};
```

and overloading:

```
template <class T1>
void A<T1>::foo(T1 t, const std::shared_ptr<B>& b, const std::shared_ptr<C>& c)
{
    std::cout << "Foo specalized" << std::endl;
}
```

works ok

And if you want your overload to work for shared pointers of every type you can do:

A.h

```
class A
{
    // ...
    template <class T2, class T3>
    void foo(T1 t1, const shared_ptr<T2>& t2, const shared_ptr<T3>& t3);
};
```

A-inl.h

```
template <class T1>
template <class T2, class T3>
void A<T1>::foo(T1 t1, const shared_ptr<T2>& t2, const shared_ptr<T3>& t3)
{
    std::cout << "Foo specalized" << std::endl;
}
```